# Are proofs by "maximality" equivalent to proofs by induction?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

*I apologize for the lack of proper terminology; I have zero experience in this field.*

**What I mean by "proof by maximality":** One way to show that a set $A$ has a certain property $p$ is to assume there is a largest proper subset $X \subsetneq A$ which verifies $p$ and then show that there is another subset of $A$ larger than $X$, $Y\supsetneq X$, which also verifies $p$, a contradiction. Then one concludes that $A$ verifies $p$.

Now, these kinds of proofs seem strikingly similar to proofs by induction, where one assumes that a proposition holds for $n$ (i.e. $n$ is the *largest* number that verifies it) and then proves that it must hold for $n+1$ as well and therefore, by the principle of induction, it is true for all the elements of $\mathbb{N}.$ The "base case" is similar as well, since in proofs by "maximality" one first has to show that there exists a subset verifying the property $p$.

I was wondering if there is a link between these two proof techniques and, if at all, **how one can be turned into the other**. I am having trouble trying to formalize this. Where can I learn more about it?

Comment: Yes; see e.g.Enderton, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA34), **Ch.1.4 Induction and Recursion**.

Comment: See [Structural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) : "a proof method used in mathematical logic that is a generalization of mathematical induction used to prove that some proposition $P(x)$ holds for all elements of some sort of recursively defined structure, such as formulas, lists, or trees."

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA, very helpful. Will look into those.

Comment: The principle you describe is invalid unless $A$ is finite. The structural induction principles referred to by Mauro assume some restriction on the subsets $X \subseteq A$. E.g., your principle is valid for all finite subsets of the natural numbers but not valid for all subsets of the natural numbers. Being finite is a property that satisfies the conditions of your principle - there is no maximal  finite set of natural numbers. But not every set of natural numbers is finite.

Answer (score -2):

Well, not familiar with your argument. But the induction axiom goes in the direction of maximality.

Let ${\Bbb N}_0$ be the set of natural numbers. Let $N$ be a subset of ${\Bbb N}_0$ such that $0\in N$ and with each $n\in N$ we have $n+1\in N$. Then $N = {\Bbb N}_0$.

Comment: I don't see how a proof by maximality can be turned into one by induction, though.